# Is there a way to filter Twilio call logs?

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to filter the Twilio call logs (https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/calls) according to which TwiML app (or callback url) was used to handle the request?

I have a ton of numbers assigned to various apps, and this would be really helpful for doing some basic usage analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this in the Twilio web interface (see [@phalt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939899/is-there-a-way-to-filter-twilio-call-logs/21940474?noredirect=1#comment33262016_21940474)), but you can do this using Excel:

1. Export the logs into an Excel spreadsheet
2. Set up a spreadsheet that maps the phone number in the log to the endpoint assigned to that phone number
3. Use VLOOKUP to pull the endpoint URL or TwiML app into the log spreadsheet.
4. Filter, sort, etc. using Excel's filtering capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio employee here.

[TWiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) is used to respond to Twilio when your web app is sent a request, so TWiML won't work.

For filtering results you can use our [REST api](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list) to poll the logs in your account and filter your results too.

This cURL example will get all the calls back since January 1st 2014:

```
$ curl -G https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls.json \
-d "StartTime=2014-01-01" \
-u '{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}'
```

Check out the REST api docs for more information: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list

We've got a REST client in a bunch of different languages, check out the helper libraries here - https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear in my question.  Not trying to use TwiML to filter the logs.  I want to filter/segment the logs according to which TwiML app or callback endpoing was used to handle the request.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: So you want to filter the logs based on the TWiML that was sent in the response back to Twilio? Or based on the URL endpoint that Twilio triggered?

Comment: I see - so considering a single phone number can only have 2 uri endpoints, one for SMS and one for voice, you can infer the URL endpoint based on the action that occurred on that phone number. At the moment there is no way to see the URL that was requested by Twilio through our REST client. If you have anymore issues, contact our support team at help@twilio.com

Comment: That sounds like what I thought.  Basically, I would have to export the logs to Excel, make an excel table mapping phone number to endpoint (b/c there are too many for me to just do it in my head) and then use VLOOKUP to tie the tables together.  Not the end of the world, not as easy as it could be.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Twilio Helper Libraries

[helper libraries](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183588-Exporting-SMS-and-Call-Logs)